# triangle pointing arrow for popup menu

Tags: html, css, menu, popup

I have a menu (sidebar), when you hover over the corresponding menu item, a second column with a submenu is displayed. I need to make a triangle-pointer, as in the picture (in the question). I can’t understand how this can be done. Share your opinion, please. Thank!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/su151.png

```css
.main {
  font-family: PT Sans;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.main_menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: auto;
  background-color: #38618C;
  padding: 50px 0 0 0;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.main_menu_content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: sticky;
  top: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}
.main_menu_content_list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  text-align: center;
  height: 700px;
  width: 250px;
}

.main_menu_content_list li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.main_menu_content_list a {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 23px;
  color: #D7DFE8;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.main_menu_content_list_sub_block {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 55px;
}

.main_menu_content_list_submenu {
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  left: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #F0F6F8;
  box-shadow: 5px 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  top: -50px;
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all linear 0.1s 0s;
  width: 250px;
}

.main_menu_content_list li:hover .main_menu_content_list_submenu {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup li:first-child {
  margin: 50px 0 0 0;
}

.main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup li:not(:first-child) {
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}

.main_menu_content_list li:hover > .main_menu_content_list_submenu {
  display: flex;
}

.main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup a {
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 21px;
  color: #38618C;
}

.main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup a:hover {
  color: #38618C;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup a:active {
  color: #FF5964;
}

.main_content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">

        <div class="main_menu">
            <div class="main_menu_content">
                <ul class="main_menu_content_list">
                    <li><a href="">
                            <div class="main_menu_content_list_int"></div>Интернет
                        </a>
                        <div class="main_menu_content_list_submenu">
                            <ul class="main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup">
                                <li><a href="">Подключение</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Дополнительные услуги</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Настройка соединения</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Подключенные дома</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="">
                            <div class="main_menu_content_list_tv"></div>Телевидение
                        </a>
                        <div class="main_menu_content_list_submenu">
                            <ul class="main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup">
                                <li><a href="">Подключение</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Новости</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Акции</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Аналоговое ТВ</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Оборудование</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Настройка каналов</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Подключенные дома</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Документы</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="">
                            <div class="main_menu_content_list_video"></div>Видеонаблюдение,<br>домофон
                        </a>
                        <div class="main_menu_content_list_submenu">
                            <ul class="main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup">
                                <li><a href="">Обслуживание</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Установка</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Заявка на ремонт</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Подключение</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="">
                            <div class="main_menu_content_list_tvr"></div>ТВ Реклама
                        </a></li>
                    <li><a href="">
                            <div class="main_menu_content_list_intb"></div>Интернет для бизнеса
                        </a></li>
                    <div class="main_menu_content_list_sub_block">
                        <li><a href="">Оплата</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">О компании</a></li>
                    </div>
                    <li><a href="">
                            <div class="main_menu_content_list_sub_account"></div>Личный кабинет
                        </a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="main_content">
        </div>
        
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this css

```
.main_menu_content_list > li.haveSubmenu > a:after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border: solid 10px;
    border-color: transparent #F0F6F8 transparent transparent;
    right: 0;
    opacity: 0;
}
.main_menu_content_list > li.haveSubmenu:hover > a:after{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```css
.main {
  font-family: PT Sans;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.main_menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: auto;
  background-color: #38618C;
  padding: 50px 0 0 0;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.main_menu_content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: sticky;
  top: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}
.main_menu_content_list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  text-align: center;
  height: 700px;
  width: 250px;
}

.main_menu_content_list li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
.main_menu_content_list > li.haveSubmenu > a:after{
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 border: solid 10px;
 border-color: transparent #F0F6F8 transparent transparent;
 right: 0;
 opacity: 0;
}
.main_menu_content_list > li.haveSubmenu:hover > a:after{
 opacity: 1;
}

.main_menu_content_list a {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 23px;
  color: #D7DFE8;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.main_menu_content_list_sub_block {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 55px;
}

.main_menu_content_list_submenu {
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  left: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #F0F6F8;
  box-shadow: 5px 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  top: -50px;
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all linear 0.1s 0s;
  width: 250px;
}

.main_menu_content_list li:hover .main_menu_content_list_submenu {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup li:first-child {
  margin: 50px 0 0 0;
}

.main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup li:not(:first-child) {
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}

.main_menu_content_list li:hover > .main_menu_content_list_submenu {
  display: flex;
}

.main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup a {
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 21px;
  color: #38618C;
}

.main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup a:hover {
  color: #38618C;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup a:active {
  color: #FF5964;
}

.main_content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">

        <div class="main_menu">
            <div class="main_menu_content">
                <ul class="main_menu_content_list">
                    <li class="haveSubmenu"><a href="">
                            <div class="main_menu_content_list_int"></div>Интернет
                        </a>
                        <div class="main_menu_content_list_submenu">
                            <ul class="main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup">
                                <li><a href="">Подключение</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Дополнительные услуги</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Настройка соединения</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Подключенные дома</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="haveSubmenu"><a href="">
                            <div class="main_menu_content_list_tv"></div>Телевидение
                        </a>
                        <div class="main_menu_content_list_submenu">
                            <ul class="main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup">
                                <li><a href="">Подключение</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Новости</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Акции</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Аналоговое ТВ</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Оборудование</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Настройка каналов</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Подключенные дома</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Документы</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="haveSubmenu"><a href="">
                            <div class="main_menu_content_list_video"></div>Видеонаблюдение,<br>домофон
                        </a>
                        <div class="main_menu_content_list_submenu">
                            <ul class="main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup">
                                <li><a href="">Обслуживание</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Установка</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Заявка на ремонт</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Подключение</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="">
                            <div class="main_menu_content_list_tvr"></div>ТВ Реклама
                        </a></li>
                    <li><a href="">
                            <div class="main_menu_content_list_intb"></div>Интернет для бизнеса
                        </a></li>
                    <div class="main_menu_content_list_sub_block">
                        <li><a href="">Оплата</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">О компании</a></li>
                    </div>
                    <li><a href="">
                            <div class="main_menu_content_list_sub_account"></div>Личный кабинет
                        </a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="main_content">
        </div>
```

Comment: made some changes in code above, add "haveSubmenu" to each li those have submenu inside

Comment: The code works fine without "haveSubmenu" :-) Your answer helped me. Thank!

Comment: without adding "haveSubmenu" class it will add arrow on those menu as well which one don't have submenu inside, so better updated you css as my css above and add class on li "haveSubmenu"

Answer (score 1):

You can draw the arrow with border properties and add to the corresponding submenu popup `::before` for styling. Then, adjust the position of the arrow with `top` property for each submenu.

```
/* Add the following CSS configuration */
li:first-child ul.main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup::before {
    top: 4.5rem;
}

li:nth-child(2) ul.main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup::before {
    top: 11rem;
}

li:nth-child(3) ul.main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup::before {
    top: 18rem;
}

ul.main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup::before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    border-color: transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    left: -0.5rem;
    border-width: .5rem .5rem .5rem 0;
    border-right-color: #F0F6F8;
}
```

```css
.main {
  font-family: PT Sans;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.main_menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: auto;
  background-color: #38618C;
  padding: 50px 0 0 0;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.main_menu_content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: sticky;
  top: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}
.main_menu_content_list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  text-align: center;
  height: 700px;
  width: 250px;
}

.main_menu_content_list li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.main_menu_content_list a {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 23px;
  color: #D7DFE8;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.main_menu_content_list_sub_block {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 55px;
}

.main_menu_content_list_submenu {
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  left: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #F0F6F8;
  box-shadow: 5px 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  top: -50px;
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all linear 0.1s 0s;
  width: 250px;
}

.main_menu_content_list li:hover .main_menu_content_list_submenu {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup li:first-child {
  margin: 50px 0 0 0;
}

.main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup li:not(:first-child) {
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}

.main_menu_content_list li:hover > .main_menu_content_list_submenu {
  display: flex;
}

.main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup a {
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 21px;
  color: #38618C;
}

.main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup a:hover {
  color: #38618C;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup a:active {
  color: #FF5964;
}

.main_content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

/* Add the following CSS configuration */
li:first-child ul.main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup::before {
    top: 4.5rem;
}

li:nth-child(2) ul.main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup::before {
    top: 11rem;
}

li:nth-child(3) ul.main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup::before {
    top: 18rem;
}

ul.main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup::before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    border-color: transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    left: -0.5rem;
    border-width: .5rem .5rem .5rem 0;
    border-right-color: #F0F6F8;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">

        <div class="main_menu">
            <div class="main_menu_content">
                <ul class="main_menu_content_list">
                    <li><a href="">
                            <div class="main_menu_content_list_int"></div>Интернет
                        </a>
                        <div class="main_menu_content_list_submenu">
                            <ul class="main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup">
                                <li><a href="">Подключение</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Дополнительные услуги</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Настройка соединения</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Подключенные дома</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="">
                            <div class="main_menu_content_list_tv"></div>Телевидение
                        </a>
                        <div class="main_menu_content_list_submenu">
                            <ul class="main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup">
                                <li><a href="">Подключение</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Новости</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Акции</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Аналоговое ТВ</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Оборудование</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Настройка каналов</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Подключенные дома</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Документы</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="">
                            <div class="main_menu_content_list_video"></div>Видеонаблюдение,<br>домофон
                        </a>
                        <div class="main_menu_content_list_submenu">
                            <ul class="main_menu_content_list_submenu_popup">
                                <li><a href="">Обслуживание</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Установка</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Заявка на ремонт</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Подключение</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="">
                            <div class="main_menu_content_list_tvr"></div>ТВ Реклама
                        </a></li>
                    <li><a href="">
                            <div class="main_menu_content_list_intb"></div>Интернет для бизнеса
                        </a></li>
                    <div class="main_menu_content_list_sub_block">
                        <li><a href="">Оплата</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">О компании</a></li>
                    </div>
                    <li><a href="">
                            <div class="main_menu_content_list_sub_account"></div>Личный кабинет
                        </a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="main_content">
        </div>
        
</div>
```

Comment: Great method, bro :) Thank you!

Comment: @rabbit glad to help :)